# How to portably detect whether a compiler supports <iostream> vs <iostream.h>

Tags: c++, perl, perl-xs

I'm working on a utility that needs to be able to compile on both standard C++ compilers and pre-standard compilers.  The code can and will be thrown at just about any C++ compiler in existence.

I am looking for a means to robustly and portably determine whether the target compiler supports header files with or without an .h extension.  I will also need to detect whether namespaces are supported.  Both of these needs may or may not be possible.

A little background: The utility is the Inline::CPP language extension for Perl.  The extension automatically includes `<iostream>`, and tries to make a good guess whether a '.h' is required or not (and of course whether or not the compiler supports namespaces).  But it's far from perfect in that regard, and this issue is diminishing the breadth of the utility's usefulness.

So to reiterate the question: How do I portably detect whether a compiler supports standard headers such as `<iostream>`, or pre-standard headers such as `<iostream.h>`?

Comment: You're probably just going to have to do a bunch of preprocessor branching on things like `_MSC_VER`. Or tell people to use a compiler from the last decade.

Comment: This is not possible at compile/preprocess time other than detecting compiler version and having the guesses hard coded based on that. have you thought about making configure script?

Comment: This is what I was afraid of: That I'll have to determine the fingerprints (such as _MSC_VER) of dozens of compilers and set up a maze of preprocessor directives.

Comment: @Dani: There already is a script that installs the utility; I suppose I could ask the user to specify which is needed on his system.  It's somewhat of a quagmire.

Comment: @DavidO: if there is a script that installs the utility, make two test programs, on with `.h` and without, and check which compiles. after that generate a file called `my_iostream.h` that includes the correct version and use that file in your code.

Comment: @Dani: The hooks into the install process are limited, but I will investigate to see if that approach (which seems quite sane) is possible.  I might be able to put something into the Makefile.PL script to execute prior to configuring a MAKEFILE for the distribution.

Comment: Great.  I'm visualizing it now and believe that approach will be both possible and effective.  Here is a link to what I'm working on if anyone's interested: http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Inline::CPP  I took over maintenance on the module a couple weeks ago, and am trying to get it back on its feet again after drifting out of compatibility with modern compilers over the years.

Comment: An update a few months later: I was able to follow Dani's suggestion of test-compiling a few trial code examples within the install utility.  Based on which ones compiled correctly I was able to determine whether or not the compiler supports standard headers (and namespaces) or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not in the code, but in the build/configure system. For example in CMake, you could use [try_compile](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command%3atry_compile) and provide it a sample file.

```
...
try_compile(PRE_STANDARD_HEADERS tmp_builds pre_standard_headers_test.cpp)
if ( ${PRE_STANDARD_HEADERS} )
    add_definitions( -D PRE_STANDARD_HEADERS )
endif()
```

You'd need to make that pre_standard_headers_test.cpp .. just a simple compilable exe that #include <iostream.h> for example.

Then in your normal code just an

```
#ifdef PRE_STANDARD_HEADERS
```

would do the trick.

Comment: This is essentially the approach that I followed.  Within the Perl "Makefile.PL" (a script that programatically builds the makefile) I test-compiled some code.  Based on which code compiled and which didn't I was able to determine the capabilities of the compiler accurately enough to set up the proper configuration in makefile, and within the Perl module's configuration settings.

Comment: Coolness, I'm glad you got a working solution DavidO. If you're gonna do a lot of C++, I personally recommend investing some time in learning CMake+CTest+CPack; it does have a pretty steep leaning curve, but is like having magic powers when you're building stuff. I got started/interested after watching this hour long vid: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Ut9o4OdSC0 then went on just following the reference docs to get stuff done: http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html

Answer (score 1):

The standard approach for Linux and other Unix-friendly platforms is to use a [configure script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configure_script). The script will generate as its output a Makefile and a config.h header file that turns on or off any compiler features that your code could rely on when available.

For Windows it is kind of expected that you will provide solution and project files for Visual Studio, with a pre-generated config.h header file.